# How to give custom name to Sqoop output files

Tags: hadoop, output, hdfs, sqoop

When I import data to hive using sqoop bydefault it creates file name as part-m-0000, part-m-0001 etc on HDFS.

Is it possible to rename these files?

If i wish to give some meaningfull name like suffxing file name with date to indicate load  how can I do it?

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with sqoop directly, but you can rename them in HDFS after sqoop is done importing:

```
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
files=$(hadoop fs -ls /path-to-files | awk  '{print $8}')
for f in $files; do hadoop fs -mv $f $f$today; done
```

The first command gets today's date. The second command gets all the filenames within your directory. The third command renames those files, appending the date.

Comment: hi i will be having daily scheduled job.Each day this script should rename only newly cretead files not all the files

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can ! see [here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_additional_import_configuration_properties)

```
sqoop import -D mapreduce.output.basename=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```