# filename of the sqoop import

Tags: sqoop

When we import from RDBMS to HDFS using sqoop we will give target directory to store data, once the job completed we can see the filename as `part-m-0000` as mapper output. Is there any way we can pass the filename in which the data will stored? Is sqoop have any option like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No you can't rename it.

You can specify `--target-dir <dir>` to tell the location of **directory** where all the data is imported,

In this directory, you see many part files (e.g. `part-m-00000`). These  part files are created by various mappers (*remember `-m <number>` in your sqoop import command*)

Since data is imported in multiple files, how would you name each part file?

I did not see any additional benefit for this renaming.

Comment: is it possible to concatenate all the files and name it into a single file with sqoop?

Comment: @SathiyanS No. repartitioning output data is not supported in sqoop.

Comment: @SathiyanS you can use hadoop `getmerge` to merge these files. Example:    `hadoop fs -getmerge /sqoop/target-dir/ /desired/local/output/file.txt`

Comment: yeah trying that only, I just wanted to check any option with sqoop itself. Thanks Dev.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695790/how-to-give-custom-name-to-sqoop-output-files?rq=1), you can specify arguments passed to mapreduce with -D option, which can accept file name options:
`-Dmapreduce.output.basename=myoutputprefix`
Although this will change the basename of your file, it will not change the part numbers.

Same answers on other sites:

- [cloudera](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/Sqoop-specifying-file-name-when-importing-data/m-p/16024#M364)
- [hadoopinrealworld](http://hadoopinrealworld.com/changing-output-file-prefix-hadoop-mapreduce-job/)